# Combine Stream and Future in one Widget, any suggestions?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

I got a pretty simple problem, but I cant really figure it out. I'm not that used to asynchronous functions.
I got one function returning a `Stream<QuerySnapshot>` from my Firebase Cloud-Firestore containing data about persons. Another function is returning a `Future<String>` containing the download URL of an image, it uses a value from the stream to identify where to get the image from.

I basically just want to build a list of widgets containing both, but cant figure out how to combine the `FutureBuilder` and the `StreamBuilder`.

So I need to call the function returning the `Stream`, wait for the data to then get the `Future<String`> to identify which Image to get, to wait for the `Image.network()` to download the Image.

Its 3 asynchronous tasks in a row, one depending on the other and with 2 different return types.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can nest FutureBuilder inside StreamBuilder and just wait for the future value from the stream

Comment: check `Stream.asyncMap` method